# Dart/Flutter How to access element of Map inside a list

Tags: flutter, dart

How to access a Map element value by key, when a Map is inside a list?

```
'rooms': [
        {
          'roomNumber': 1,
          'roomBeds': 1,
          'roomColor': 1,
          'roomNumOfDwellers': 0,
          'roomDwellers': [
          ]
        },
        {
          'roomNumber': 2,
          'roomBeds': 3,
          'roomColor': 2,
          'roomNumOfDwellers': 0,
          'roomDwellers': [
          ]
        },
      ]
```

Tried this, doesn't work:

```
myPODO.rooms[1].['roomBeds']
```

The error message is:

> Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap' has no instance getter 'roomBeds'.
>   Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:5
>   Tried calling: roomBeds

Comment: Can we see how your getting myPODO?

Answer (score 3):

Store the items in a list of Map and you can then print the values by key names.

```dart
void main() {

  List<Map<String, dynamic>> rooms = [
        {
          'roomNumber': 1,
          'roomBeds': 1,
          'roomColor': 1,
          'roomNumOfDwellers': 0,
          'roomDwellers': [
          ]
        },
        {
          'roomNumber': 2,
          'roomBeds': 3,
          'roomColor': 2,
          'roomNumOfDwellers': 0,
          'roomDwellers': [
          ]
        },
      ];

  print(rooms[1]['roomBeds']);
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you very much! The problem was in the dot between rooms[1] and ['roomBeds'], it wasn't needed.

Answer (score 3):

try to replace

```
myPODO.rooms[1].['roomBeds']
```

with

```
myPODO.rooms[1]['roomBeds']
```